# How to implement transaction management in Mybatis project

Tags: spring, jax-rs, mybatis

I am currently working on a project which has already implemented mybatis.
Since this is a legacy code, the implementation is done using

1. spring
2. Mybatis
3. JAxrs

Spring application context file

```
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory"         class="com.ca.aa.ui.framework.common.mybatis.SqlSessionFactoryBeanWrapper">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:ibatis/*_mapper.xml" />

</bean>
```

There is another xml file referenced from application context

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean" name="tenantDAO">
    <property name="mapperInterface"   value="com.ca.ias.data.dao.TenantDAO"  />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

TenantDAO.java

```
public interface TenantDAO {

public List<something> somemethod1();

}
```

Then there is an service layer which access the above java class adn then persists the object

```
<bean id="issuerService" class="com.ca.ias.admin.service.IssuerServiceImpl">
    <property name="tenantDAO" ref="tenantDAO"/>
</bean>
```

there is a plain java method, which calls tenantDAO and then persists the object.

IssuerServiceImpl.java

```
public void insert(){

try{
   tenantDao.insert();
}catch(Exception e){

}finally{

}
```

How do I implement transaction manager here, please help?

Answer (score 1):

The are many ways to do that especially given that you already have spring configured. Basically you need to configure two things

1. transaction manager
2. transaction boundaries

**Transaction manager**

You need to define [transaction manager](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-strategies) in your spring context. Depending on where `dataSource` mentioned in your `sqlSessionFactory` definition comes from it may vary. Most probably you use connection pool in your project that is you have configuration of some connection pool like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
    destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
   <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
   <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
   <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

If this is the case then you need to add configuration like this to you spring context

```
<bean id="txManager" 
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

**Transaction boundaries**

The simplest way is to use [annotation driven](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) transaction demarcation.

Then you need enable it first:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

With this configuration you can use `Transactional` annotation to mark methods in your service:

```
@Transactional
public void insert(){

}

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void find(){

}
```